# Ubuntu 14 fixing fonts for agnoster

Tags: fonts, zsh

I installed oh my zsh, then I tried to apply agnoster theme, I am almost there but I have a problem with the fonts, my prompt looks like this

[image]

The problem is that seems that I have a font problem and I do not know how may I fix this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I encounter the same problem and the fonts-powerline package was missing.
A `sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline` should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you @fijiroy it did not work straight ahead, but that was the problem. I solved installing the fonts with wget.

Answer (score 1):

you should install Menlo-Powerline font patch to ~/.fonts/:
https://gist.github.com/qrush/1595572/raw/417a3fa36e35ca91d6d23ac961071094c26e5fad/Menlo-Powerline.otf